# Getting lists from Spring Boot configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

My Spring Boot application doesn't seem to be recognising lists in my configuration file (application.yml). Below is roughly what I'm trying to do.

**Java Code**:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

public class Config{
  public Config(){
  }

  public List<String> getDateFields(){
    return environment.getProperty("dates.fields", List.class);
  }
}
```

**application.yml**:

```
dates:
  fields:
  - date
  - creationDate
```

`getDateFields` returns null above. However, if I use the following...

**application.yml**:

```
dates:
  fields: creationDate
```

...it works fine and returns it as a list (albeit a single valued one). Why can't I get the list from my application.yml file? I tried checking whether `environment` even contained `dates.fields`, and `environment.containsProperty("dates.fields")` returns `false` when using the list version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use coma separated format, for your list properties if you want to load the values as List using environment.getProperty("dates.fields", List.class);

```
dates:
  fields: date, creationDate
```

that way goes well for me.

However if you want to use

```
dates:
  fields:
     - date
     - creationDate
```

Then better use the following aproach to load the properties from yaml file.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dates")
public class Config{

   private List<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();

   public List<String> getDateFields(){
      return this.fields;
   }
}
```